# I and making an app what are my choices for making a website for it

Tags: android, ios, windows, web

Hi I'm currently a making free cross platform app (Win7, Android, Windows 10, IOS).And I want to make a website for it, But I don't have much experience in web design. So I wonder if there is any good platform/CMS/Template I can use to make the website quickly? That's the site I want to create briefly:

1. A homepage with a big download button, a screenshot some information
2. An about page
3. Another download page that includes more download options: such as downloading for other platforms that the visitor is currently using and beta versions.
4. A contact page.
5. And may be a blog

But please keep in mind that I want a clean, minimalist, responsive and easy-to-use design
One thing to consider is that the target market for my app is *everyone*, and most of them are not computer nerds so the website must be intuitive to use.
One more thing, how can the website detect what OS is the visitor using?

Comment: seriously?! Maybe you want also a bacon sandwich?

Comment: Maybe I need one, I don't ask you to make the website form me, I just ask what are my choices, what other developers do, that's all

Comment: Ok we keep in that in mind, that you are a lazy little guy asking other for solutions in a manner I never saw here ever again. And thats why, here is a [potato](http://pngimg.com/upload/potato_PNG421.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should go for wordpress cms. Its very quick and easy to use to setup a website with least knowledge required. you can start with famous five minute wordpress installation at here [Five Min Install Wordpress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/how-to-install-wordpress/)